# android edittext automatically enters the input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this EditText for password that only allows 4 characters. My Question is, how do i make it enter the password after inputting 4 characters? Without the use of button, just after the 4th character it will enter the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a textChangeListener.

```
Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() == 4)
      // length is 4 characters do what you want to do here.
      Toast.makeText(context, s, 100).show();
   }
  });
```